# java.lang.InternalError: a fault occurred in a recent unsafe memory access operation in compiled Java code

Tags: java, memory, jvm

I was wondering if some of the JVM gurus out there can briefly explain the following error. What does it actually mean in technical terms and what are the sequences of events that can lead to this error?

```
java.lang.InternalError: a fault occurred in a recent unsafe memory access operation in compiled Java code
```

Comment: How did *you* get the error in the first place?

Comment: Have you tried Googling the error message?  There are some interesting results that might explain it, like https://gist.github.com/rednaxelafx/1372200/58a95fbf57be0930ceb448280f84e22217cfa37f in which someone looked at the C code of the JVM and found something about a SIGBUS error.

Comment: I didn't personally run into this error, but I have been looking through some bugs reported in other software projects, like Kafka for instance and saw this particular error pop-up during different scenarios with different stacks. I was just curious about the error.

Comment: Check out for disk errors (sudo dmesg -T)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This error means that `sun.misc.Unsafe.getX()` or `putX()` memory access resulted in [`SIGBUS`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_error) error, which was then caught by JVM and translated to asynchronous `InternalError`.

A bit more details:

- `sun.misc.Unsafe` is JDK private API that allows to access native memory directly from Java. This API is a foundation for Direct ByteBuffers and particularly [MappedByteBuffers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/MappedByteBuffer.html).
- In certain cases an access to memory-mapped region of a file may lead to OS-level exception, namely `SIGBUS`. Typical examples are:

  1. A memory-mapped buffer is accessed after the underlying file has been truncated.
  2. A file on a network drive has been mapped to memory, and the mapped buffer is accessed after the network connection has been lost.
  3. An attempt to write to a page mapped to a file on `tmpfs` filesystem results in out-of-memory (by default `tmpfs` space is limited by 50% of total RAM).
- HotSpot JVM cannot efficiently detect these problems beforehand. It compiles `Unsafe.getX / putX` calls to a simple memory access instruction. Additional checks to see if a memory region is valid would be too expensive.
- Instead JVM handles `SIGBUG` signal. If it sees the error has happened in `Unsafe` call, it posts `InternalError` to current thread and continues execution.
- `IOException` would be more appropriate, but JVM cannot throw it or any other exception, since `ByteBuffer` public contract does not allow its `get/put` methods to throw any exception.
- If `Unsafe` memory access has failed in JIT-compiled method, JVM does not throw an exception immediately (again, it would be too expensive for such hot ByteBuffer API). Instead it posts *asynchronous* `InternalError` to the current thread. It means the error would be actually thrown at the nearest native method or at the nearest call to VM runtime. Hence the word *"recent"* in the error message.

See [JDK-4454115 comments](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4454115?focusedCommentId=12548406&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-12548406) describing the solution for the related JDK bug.

Answer (score 5):

This can also happen due to disk space issues.

Answer (score 2):

This error may be induced by corrupted index which in turn becomes corrupted due to `java.io.IOException: No space left on device`

Look into your_kafka_home/logs/server.log

It all starts like this:

```
[2019-11-22 17:27:25,204] FATAL [Replica Manager on Broker 1]: Halting due to unrecoverable I/O error while handling produce request:  (kafka.server.ReplicaManager)
kafka.common.KafkaStorageException: I/O exception in append to log 'xxx-response-1-0'
    at kafka.log.Log.append(Log.scala:443)
    at kafka.cluster.Partition.$anonfun$appendRecordsToLeader$1(Partition.scala:451)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: No space left on device
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write(FileDispatcherImpl.java:60)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.write(FileChannelImpl.java:211)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.record.MemoryRecords.writeFullyTo(MemoryRecords.java:82)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.record.FileRecords.append(FileRecords.java:159)
    at kafka.log.LogSegment.append(LogSegment.scala:110)
    at kafka.log.Log.append(Log.scala:429)
    ... 21 more
```

is followed by (possibly mutilple times):

```
[2019-11-22 17:28:00,395] WARN Found a corrupted index file due to requirement
failed: Corrupt index found, index file (/opt/kafka/kafka-logs/__consumer_offsets- 
9/00000000000000000000.index) has non-zero size but the last offset is 0 which is no
larger than the base offset 0.}. deleting /opt/kafka/kafka-logs/__consumer_offsets-9
/00000000000000000000.timeindex, /opt/kafka/kafka-logs/__consumer_offsets-9
/00000000000000000000.index and rebuilding index... (kafka.log.Log)
```

and finally comes to :

```
[2019-11-22 17:28:02,025] FATAL [Kafka Server 1], Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
java.lang.InternalError: **a fault occurred in a recent unsafe memory access operation in compiled Java code**
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:12)
    at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.inLock(CoreUtils.scala:213)
    at kafka.log.TimeIndex.maybeAppend(TimeIndex.scala:107)
    at kafka.log.LogSegment.$anonfun$recover$1(LogSegment.scala:238
```