# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment (SIGBUS (0x7))

Tags: java, jvm, jmh

We have written JMH custom bench marking to our test cases,  expected inputs we are reading from properties file. For each iteration we read input from properties file then we execute our actual logic, we are capturing time in milliseconds before and after execution  of our logic. While starting the test case we pass number of iterations as argument, until 2000 iterations it is working fine. If we give iteration number more than 2000 then we are getting below error.

> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>   SIGBUS (0x7) at pc=0xx, pid=xx, tid=0xx
>   Problematic frame:v StubRoutines:jlong_disjoint_arraycopy
>   forked VM failed with exit code 134

Comment: Thinks the best way is to Report it as bug: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448163/a-fatal-error-has-been-detected-by-the-java-runtime-environment-sigsegv-libjvm

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521186/how-to-debug-a-native-java-crash-on-linux

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45536678/3448419) is a list of typical reasons of SIGBUS. Are you using MappedByteBuffers? Can you share the full hs_err.log?